# Unable to resolve jira-rest-java-client dependency

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am writing a Java service to access JIRA. And I am using `jira-rest-java-clien`t.
But I am unable to resolve the error in the pom file for the `jira-rest-java-client` dependency.

[image]

So I added the JAR explicitly in the build path but the error in pom file exists.
 [image]

Also, my maven settings are such that it is trying to download the artifacts from my org's artifact repository but looks like it is not having any JIRA/Atlassian dependencies there.

Can someone please tell what is it I am doing wrong?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add this dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
   <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0-m31</version>
</dependency>
```

after configuring the following repository?

```
<repository>
   <id>opencast-public</id>
   <url>http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
</repository>
```

Or even better, you could add the Atlassian Maven Repository to your pom.xml. You can find detailed information here: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Atlassian+Maven+Repositories

Comment: I had a similar issue and the only solution was to add the Atlassians Maven public repo. It worked like a charm. Added the <repository> element in the pom.xml file and it did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-m4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-m2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.openengsb.wrapped</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-m32.w1</version>
</dependency>
```

have you tried with this one?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve atlassian artifacts - add a repository to your pom (or settings.xml)

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>atlassian</id>
        <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```